# Clarification on how to use FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Just posted before and need clarification on a property. (Note I know this question is similar to others and hence I tried looking elsewhere for the solution but couldn't find the exact one for this situation).

I'm rather new to programming and don't know how to make a `DataGridView` scroll to the row selected by a user. I tried using `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` but am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to 'int'

Which occurs when I try to bring the selected row by the user to the top of the datagridview:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[i]
```

Here is the full code:

```
String searchVal = textBox1.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchVal))
    {
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the index of the row that is the first row displayed on the DataGridView.

You already have the index stored in `i` ... try just using that:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
```

---

To address your second question in the comments, here's how you can find the first exact match (if any):

```
var selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells[0].Value) == searchVal);

if (selectedRow != null)
{
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    dataGridView1.Update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works but Another quick clarification, when the user types the number '9' rows with the number 9, 19, 29, 39, 49 pop up. I only want the row with the number 9.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `i` instead of `dataGridView1.Rows[i]`

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
```

Comment: Another quick clarification, when the user types the number '9' rows with the number 9, 19, 29, 39, 49 pop up. I only want the row with the number 9.