# How to handle DatagridView scroll event before it makes any changes

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll

I'm trying to override scroll functionality on DatagridView. 
(DGV with fixed RowCount which on scroll request refresh it self with new "scrolled" values instead of scrolling down to next values)

And I need to react myself to event and disable DatagridView to react to that event (disable it to scroll).

Something like:

```
protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
{            
    ProcessScroll(e);

    //Distable DGV processing scroll request
    //base.OnScroll(e); 
}
```

However this event occurs after scrolling is done. And for instance FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex in this point have new value after scroll.

So please can does anyone know how to react to this event before it makes any changes, and disable it to make any changes ?

I cant just catch mouse wheel event, or detect presed key, because you can scroll through DatagridView while you selecting cell by mouse.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but how about storing the value of `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` and incase you want to "disable" the scroll, just assign it the previous value.

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356809/clarification-on-how-to-use-firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex))

**Edit:**
After testing it, this will make the gridview nto to scroll, but the scroll bars are still scrolling (with no affect).
Which bring me to the next suggestion:
If you do not want to allow to scroll your grid view, simply remove the scroll bars...

```
this.gv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Yes, this is possible way how to solve the problem, however this will always lead to DGV scroll and countermeasure reaction. So you'll need to scroll DGV twice. I'm more likely trying to catch scroll event/request and process it by myself and avoid DGV reaction.

Comment: @WhiteHead I have updated my answer.... I am not sure if this is what you meant. Maybe it would be best if you elaborate about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: this will lead to disabling scrollbars of DGV, howerver you have few more ways how to scroll with dgv. For instance page down, arrows, arrows with ctrl, selecting cells out of the visible range etc. This all will lead to scroll sdgv and it this point (doesnt matter what invoked this scroll) i dont want dgv to perform scroll but refresh displayed values. It has to be done this in my case :(